# Troubles with Jenkins: unable to run jUnit tests.

Tags: java, junit, jenkins

All tests, that creates or removes files and dirs fails. I try to use env var to point root directory from surefire plugin(${WORKSPACE}), manually at pom.xml (e.g. ${env.WORKSPACE}). I even set those workspace dir directly in test code (String WORKSPACE="/ud/rpt_trunk_b"). But tests fails anyway. Does anyone uses jUnit with Jenkins?

Thanks.

Comment: I think a lot of people will use JUnit with Jenkins when programming Java. ;-) You need to put here a piece of test code which fails and all relevant configuration files like you pom.xml to get people to help you. With your sparse information there is not way to help you.

Comment: Did you check permissions for user the Jenkins is run under? Do you see any surefire reports created by Jenkins anywhere?

Comment: Are you using custom workspace? `/ud/rpt_trunk_b` certainly does not look like something Jenkins will set by default. To check where your workspace actually is, echo ${WORKSPACE} in a shell/batch build step.

Comment: There are some tests form testcase that runs correctly. So, there is OK with permissions. Tests fails on Jenkins just like they fails locally, when there is some i/o errors - unable to write (or even locate) to test dirs.

Comment: /ud/rpt_trunk_b is a value of $WORKSPACE env var. Basically, its a folder, where trunk branch builds.

Comment: My unit tests, if they need to write and delete files, always use the temporary directory to do so (`System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")`). This one, AFAIK, i guaranteed to exist and be writable whatever the environment and current directory is. It also avoids cluttering the workspace with files that it shouldn't contain.

Comment: @ psed : Please provide more information like exception stack trace..